# Changing ownership not permitted in BitBake

Tags: linux, permissions

I’m compiling a Yocto project with BitBake.

A recipe of BitBake try to change the permission of some directories and files using `chown` command. The problem is that the command fails because of **changing ownership operation not permitted**.

BitBake command is launched by user luca, that is also a sudoers.
If I type `ls -l` what I see in the problematic folder is:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 luca luca 1875 May 13 17:10 arm-thumb-mutex_db5.patch
-rw-r--r--  1 luca luca   33 May 13 17:10 configure.sstate
drwxr-xr-x 16 luca luca 4096 May 13 17:10 db-6.0.30
-rw-r--r--  1 luca luca  665 May 13 17:10 fix-parallel-build.patch
drwxr-xr-x  3 luca luca 4096 May 13 19:11 image
drwxr-xr-x  2 luca luca 4096 May 13 19:11 temp
```

Obviously if I manually type, for example, `sudo chowwn 777 image` it works, but I cannot change the BitBake script that causes the error.

What’s wrong with my permissions and user?

Comment: what happens when you run the entire script as sudo?

Comment: `sudo bitbake core image-minimal` is not working. Error: **command not found**. If I try to launnch bitbake as su it gives me error because of bitbake has not to be run as root

Comment: Only a privileged process can change the owner of a file. If that doesn't answer your question, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm quite new in linux environments. I added to /etc/sudoers the luca user to have all acceess: `luca ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`.  Doesn't that grant to luca root priviledges? I found out that the script perform `chown -R root:root ${D}` where ${D} is the directory that has to be chowned

Comment: That grants luca root privileges ONLY when invoked....via sudo.  so instead of running `myscript arg1 arg2`, run `sudo myscript arg1 arg2`.  The entire thing will run as root

Comment: This means that the bitbake code, that invoke the chown command, is a bug. Because of a standard user cannot use chown command directly. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

At the end I did chmod 777 of the whole folder of sources and all start to work. Probably permissions on scripts or exec files. Thanks to all for support.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving similiar errors in bitbake. In my case this was due to pseudo utility failing, but Yocto not clearly showing the errors and halting. Instead it continued until it could not do `chmod -R dir` as normal user. The utility 'Pseudo' is used to intercept `chown`, `chmod` calls, track them in a sqlite db. They act like they are changing your RFS file permissions, but doesn't actually require root. In my case if you searched for the error in the pkg that failed:

```
build/tmp/work/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc-runtime/linaro-4.9-r2015.03/temp> grep pseudo *
log.do_install:ERROR: ld.so: object 'libpseudo.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

log.do_install.17098:ERROR: ld.so: object 'libpseudo.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

This was because someone had previously had set security capabilities for previous development activity with:

```
setcap cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip /bin/bash or to /usr/bin/python. To fix: setcap -r /bin/bash
```

This hard to find post clued me in to this: http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-core/2012-February/056779.html